# Return tree for function with non-binary tree

Tags: haskell, tree

I have a non-binary tree:

```
data MultTree b = DataNode b | IndexNode Int Int [MultTree b] deriving (Show)
```

**Note**: `DataNode's` are treated like leafs and `IndexNode's` like branches.

Now I try to achieve that in `IndexNode` the smaller `Int` value is set to the smallest value of `DataNode` of the subtree and the bigger `Int` value is set to the biggest value of `DataNode` of the subtree.

For `IndexNode's` without a subtree the smaller `Int` value is set to `minBound::Int` and the bigger one to `maxBound::Int`

This is my function so far:

```
dataInterval:: (Ord a) => MultTree a -> MultTree a
dataInterval (DataNode x) = (DataNode x)
dataInterval(IndexNode x y [])
      | x > y  = (IndexNode (maxBound :: Int) (minBound :: Int) [])
      | x < y  = (IndexNode (minBound :: Int) (maxBound :: Int) [])
      | x == y = (IndexNode x y [])
datenInterval (IndexNode x y subtrees)
      | x > y  = (IndexNode (maxValue subtrees) (minValue subtrees) (map (dataInterval subtrees)))
      | x < y  = (IndexNode (minValue subtrees) (maxValue subtrees) (map (dataInterval subtrees)))
      | x == y = (IndexNode x y (map (dataInterval subtrees)))
```

have to call the function `dataInterval` recursively.

Now I do not know how to do that, because `dataInterval` expects a tree but somehow I have to call the complete list. `dataInterval` does not allow that.

**Question**: How can I achieve calling `dataInterval` recursively by using the subtrees in the list? So each tree of `subtrees` list will be called ?

I think it might be some functionality like map, but returning subtrees instead of a list.

At the moment the **error message** looks like that:

> Couldn't match expected type MultTree a2
>                     with actual type [MultTree a]
>       * In the first argument of datenIntervalle, namely subtrees
>         In the first argument of map, namely (datenIntervalle subtrees)
>         In the third argument of  IndexNode, namely
>           (map (datenIntervalle subtrees))

**sample tree & complete code:**

```
t2 :: MultTree Int
t2 = IndexNode 3 42 [IndexNode 7 8 [DataNode 3, DataNode 5, DataNode 7, DataNode 9], DataNode 6, IndexNode 10 23 [DataNode 99, DataNode 78, DataNode 24]]

dataList:: MultTree a -> [a]
dataList(DataNode x) = [x]
dataList(IndexNode _ _ subtress) = concat' (map dataList subtress)

maxValue :: (Ord a) => MultTree a -> a
maxValue tree = maximum (dataList tree)

minValue :: (Ord a) => MultTree a -> a
minValue tree = minimum (dataList tree)

dataInterval:: (Ord a) => MultTree a -> MultTree a
dataInterval(DataNode x) = (DataNode x)
dataInterval(IndexNode x y [])
      | x > y  = (IndexNode (maxBound :: Int) (minBound :: Int) [])
      | x < y  = (IndexNode (minBound :: Int) (maxBound :: Int) [])
      | x == y = (IndexNode x y [])
dataInterval(IndexNode x y subtrees)
      | x > y  = (IndexNode (maxValue subtrees) (minValue subtrees) (map (dataInterval subtrees)))
      | x < y  = (IndexNode (minValue subtrees) (maxValue subtrees) (map (dataInterval subtrees)))
      | x == y = (IndexNode x y (map (dataInterval subtrees)))
```

Comment: Your `dataIntervalsubtrees` `minValue` and `maxValue` are not defined, afaik?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem : sorry, I have updated my Question.

Comment: If you say: "Now I try to achieve that in IndexNode the smaller Int value is set to the smallest DataNode of the subtree and the bigger Int value is set to the biggest DataNode of the subtree." isn't it required that type b is Int due to IndexNode Int Int ...? Furthermore, just for clarification, are DataNodes are always leafs of the tree?

Comment: @SlavenGlumac: In my explanation was a "value of" missing. I have updated my post. So the smaller int of an IndexNode is set to the smallest value you can find in the leafs of the subtree. And the bigger Int of the IndexNode is set to the biggest value you can find in the leafs of the subtree. 
Yes, DataNodes are always leafs.

Comment: Instead of `map (dataInterval subtrees)` you want `map dataInterval subtrees` - this is actually just what the type error is telling you - besides that it seems like your code compiles just fine.

Comment: I have removed the the curved bracket and get an error. I would really appreciate it if you post some code. My error message: Couldn't match expected type `MultTree Int'
                  with actual type `[MultTree a]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post answer on your question also answering your last comment:

> I have removed the the curved bracket and get an error. I would really appreciate it if you post some code. My error message: Couldn't match expected type MultTree Int' with actual type [MultTree a]'

The problem here is that you specify type of `minBound :: Int`. But in type of your function you said that you have tree of any type `a` which is `Ord`.

```
dataInterval:: (Ord a) => MultTree a -> MultTree a
```

So, `Int` is not equals to `a`. If you don't want your tree be polymorphic, you can just have `dataInterval :: MultTree Int -> MultTree Int` for example.
But this is not the best solution. You can use `minBound` and `maxBound` for polymorphic type but you need to add `Bounded` constraint to `a` in type signature. And you don't need to specify type of `minBound` in your function because *Haskell* has type inference. So here is complete working example (I also removed some `()` because *Haskell* is not *Lisp*):

```
data MultTree b = DataNode b | IndexNode b b [MultTree b] deriving (Show)

t2 :: MultTree Int
t2 = IndexNode 3 42 [ IndexNode 7 8 [ DataNode 3
                                     , DataNode 5
                                     , DataNode 7
                                     , DataNode 9
                                     ]
                    , DataNode 6
                    , IndexNode 10 23 [ DataNode 99
                                      , DataNode 78
                                      , DataNode 24
                                      ]
                    ]

dataList :: MultTree a -> [a]
dataList (DataNode x)             = [x]
dataList (IndexNode _ _ subtrees) = flattenSubtrees subtrees

flattenSubtrees :: [MultTree a] -> [a]
flattenSubtrees = concatMap dataList

maxValue :: Ord a => [MultTree a] -> a
maxValue trees = maximum (flattenSubtrees trees)

minValue :: Ord a => [MultTree a] -> a
minValue trees = minimum (flattenSubtrees trees)

dataInterval :: (Bounded a, Ord a) => MultTree a -> MultTree a
dataInterval (DataNode x) = DataNode x
dataInterval node@(IndexNode x y [])
      | x > y  = IndexNode maxBound minBound []
      | x < y  = IndexNode minBound maxBound []
      | x == y = node
dataInterval (IndexNode x y subtrees)
      | x > y  = IndexNode (maxValue subtrees) (minValue subtrees) mappedSubtrees
      | x < y  = IndexNode (minValue subtrees) (maxValue subtrees) mappedSubtrees
      | x == y = IndexNode x y mappedSubtrees
  where
    mappedSubtrees = map dataInterval subtrees
```

I want to notice that this function implementation is not efficient. Because you traverse full tree each time you need to evaluate min and max values whereas in reality it's enough to traverse only last level after you found result for `subtrees`. Result of function call on `t2` is:

```
ghci> dataInterval t2 
IndexNode 3 99 [IndexNode 3 9 [DataNode 3,DataNode 5,DataNode 7,
DataNode 9],DataNode 6,IndexNode 24 99 [DataNode 99,DataNode 78,
DataNode 24]]
```

Comment: `flattenSubtrees = concatMap dataList` why should't here be a parameter? like `flattenSubtrees = concatMap dataList subtrees` ?

Comment: @jublikon Because I used eta-reduction here. `flattenSubtrees = concatMap dataList subtrees` is not valid definition because compiler doesn't know what is `subtrees`. Other valid definition is `flattenSubtrees subtrees = concatMap dataList subtrees` but, as I said, this definition is eta-equivalent to `flattenSubtrees = concatMap dataList`. Or in human words, you can remove common suffix of parts to the left and to the right of `=` sign.